# Instantly upload image when selecting when creating new content

Tags: entities, media, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I automatically upload images on file selection rather than pressing the upload button?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31121/how-can-i-automatically-upload-images-on-file-selection-rather-than-pressing-the)

What I need is for my users to attach a picture and a video to their nodes. I'm using CCK and [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) (among others), and I know that there is an image and video upload field for them; my problem is that I want it somewhat difference with a bit "cleaner" design.

Right now it looks like this:

[image: screenshot #1]

But what I want is something [like the following](http://www.atwebresults.com/php_ajax_image_upload/) (Sleeker More "Web 2.0" onChange Use)

[image: screenshot #2]

The idea is that the image automatically uploads when selecting and then displaying, maybe a small preview or otherwise just the image name with an possibility to delete it and upload a new.

Are there any module, hack or suggestion on how I can do this within Drupal?