# Removing the upload button in managed files

Tags: 7, forms

I want to save a image file  into my custom content type using forms api and `node_save()`.

The below code works fine but I also get the upload button as it default in managed_file .

I don't want the upload button. So I tried `type=file` but it did not work. How can I remove the upload button ?

Also if you just select the file and submit the form it works so I really need to just find a way to remove the upload button.

```
$form['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'File',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://my-files/'
);
```

Comment: If you remove the upload button how will people choose a file to upload?

Comment: The form type has two buttons browse and upload. Upload is only for ajax. The form works fine if you only use browse and then click submit on the form. Any idea how to get this done ?

Comment: I do not suggest using it for multiple file attachment!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The work to separate out the `managed_file` element is done in [`file_managed_file_process()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--file--file.module/function/file_managed_file_process/7), which is the default `#process` function for that type of element.

To hide the upload button you need to implement your own simple `#process` function for the element:

```
function MYMODULE_my_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'File',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://my-files/',
    '#process' => array('MYMODULE_my_file_element_process')
  );

  return $form;
}

function MYMODULE_my_file_element_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $element = file_managed_file_process($element, $form_state, $form);
  $element['upload_button']['#access'] = FALSE;
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: Clive you are simply the best ! I wud buy you a cup of coffee if we had done this in person. Also how did you figure this out ? Share some light on this

Comment: Well thanks for the coffee anyway :) I just went into the core `file` module, looked at the `file_element_info()` function (implementation of [`hook_element_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7) which is responsible for declaring form element types) and looked at the functions declared for the `managed_file` type to see where it was getting expanded. Then I used the `devel` module to find out where in the process I could hook into it and voila!

Comment: wow I will give it a shot . this is a good learning example for me

Comment: Have you seen the [Pro Drupal Development book](http://www.drupalbook.com/) by any chance? If you're serious about getting into Drupal it's an absolutely fantastic resource, it really explains how Drupal works from the ground up

Comment: thanks, I will get the book. will start reading it from tomorrow.

Comment: I was adapting this approach to a module dealing with a content type containing an image field, and found that if I replaced the #process functions that were there with my own (per the above), I lost the preview of the image once one was added to the node.  I was able to keep the preview by adding my module's #process function to those that were already there.  This took a form_alter handler for that form, but I needed that to get my hands on the form anyway.  So far, no problems.

Comment: i love you so much Clive, worked perfectly, thanks so much!

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function MYMODULE_my_file_element_process is what i am getting with this approach. Drupal 7.26. Any ideas? thank you

Comment: Hi clive..I was facing the same issue at @vishal mention above.I was used you code and its working fine,but problem here is error message displaying in inproper place.(at middle in form).Plz give any solution for this.

Comment: Of course it can be useful for some single file attachment. For multiple file attachment you will need Upload button. Basically, that's the reason of having this button!

Answer (score 0):

@Clive code doesn't work for me

```
function MYMODULE_my_file_element_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $element = file_managed_file_process($element, $form_state, $form);
  $element['upload_button']['#access'] = FALSE;
  return $element;
}
```

Invert params in the function's call does the trick

```
function MYMODULE_my_file_element_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $element = file_managed_file_process($element, $form, &$form_state);
  $element['upload_button']['#access'] = FALSE;
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Upload File Replace](https://drupal.org/project/upload_replace) module:

> This is a small utility module that automatically stops Drupal from renaming new files upload via filefield CCK. When 2 files with the same name exist, the older files will be renamed.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Based in this tread I found the way to change the text “['#value']” in the submit button to the file upload in the web form.

Put it in the template.php of your theme and its done.

```
function MYTHEME_form_webform_client_form_FORMID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['submitted']['photo_file_photo']['#process'] = array('MYTHEME_my_file_element_process');
}

function MYTHEME_my_file_element_process($element, &$form_state, &$form) {
  $element = file_managed_file_process($element, $form_state, $form);
  //$element['upload_button']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $element['upload_button']['#value'] = 'Put me in pls';
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 this works for me: (disable ajax for the field)

```
$form['document'] = [
  '#title' => $this->t('Document'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => [],
  ],
];
```

And add this to your_theme.theme file: (hide the upload button).

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_file_managed_file().
 */
function your_theme_preprocess_file_managed_file(&$variables) {
  switch ($variables['element']['#id']) {
    case 'edit-document':
      $variables['element']['upload_button']['#access'] = FALSE;
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding a element process hook works but seems like overkill to me.  in situations like this where its just an visual thing, CSS is the best way to go IMO since every upload button has its own id anyway.

```
#edit-image-upload-button{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Yes I knew about the css but I wanted to do it from the element hook . Thank you :)