# How to change 'upload' and 'choose file' text that generates form type managed_file

Tags: forms, files

```
$form['cv'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Vaš CV'),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#progress_message' => t('Molimo Vas sačekajte...'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf doc docx'),
        'file_validate_size' => array(5*1024*1024),
    ),
    '#description' => t('Dozvoljeni formati: pdf, doc, docx. Max 5MB'),
);
```

[image]

Comment: You can change 'Upload' with a simple form alter. 'Choose File' is set by the browser, and can't be changed without a hack. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file

Comment: But that is the problem I was trying with form alter it hasn't listed. I also try with '#process' and '#pre_render' but I hadn't succeeded

Comment: `#process` is the right way - see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32358/removing-the-upload-button-in-managed-files for a code example

Comment: Yes thanks, I did it :) also changed remove button text. I totally forgot that I can't change 'Choose File' text that is set by browser :D so I spend my time looking for changing this text because it's first element. I found that solution earlier, Stupid me. Thanks again!