# File Upload Form

Tags: 7, forms, files

Thanks to some help from [clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive). I've cleaned up the code below. Now it appears I need to do some tweaking with my submit handler as my files are still getting mark as temporary in the `file_managed` table. Also is there a way to stop drupal from adding the `_` in front of the file extension on upload?

**Form**

```
$form['model_wrapper_container']['ios_file'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('IOS File'),
  '#size' => 22,
  '#upload_location' => 'public://ios_images',
  '#upload_validators' => array(
  'file_validate_extensions' => array('bin aes tar'),
  ),
);
```

**Submit Handler**

```
function iosupload_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Load the file via file.fid.
  $file = file_load($form_state['values']['ios_file']);
  // Change status to permanent.
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  // Save.
  file_save($file);
}
```

Comment: To offer another approach...you could use the managed_file type (which will save having to do the file upload yourself) along with a bit of javascript to auto-press the upload button. It should achieve the same effect. There's an example at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31121/how-can-i-automatically-upload-images-on-file-selection-rather-than-pressing-the/31453#31453 if you're interested

Comment: @Clive I like the sandbox module that works pretty slick! Next issue is how do I get around the allowed file types, and tell it where it should be uploaded in the public file system? Thanks

Comment: If you're using a managed_file you can put something like `'#upload_location' => 'public://path/to/folder'` on the form element, and Drupal will handle the rest :)

Comment: @Clive Duh yeah I had that in my submit handler above... I'm going to post refreshed code and reword my question current questions. Thanks