# Image field: How to directly upload an image to get a preview, after choosing a file

Tags: forms, media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I automatically upload images on file selection rather than pressing the upload button?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31121/how-can-i-automatically-upload-images-on-file-selection-rather-than-pressing-the)

I'm trying to change the default behavior of Drupal when adding an image through image field on a content type.

When you choose an image to assign to a node, it's not directly uploaded. You also need to click "upload" to display the preview of your image, and this is not really user friendly.

How can I change this (programmatically) to make Drupal start uploading directly the image after choosing the file.

Thank you for help