# How can i put popup box captcha on managed file remove button?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, files

Can We write function for remove button as I want to display Captcha in popup on Remove button for security reason.

same type of some function like used in below post.

[How can I automatically upload images on file selection rather than pressing the upload button?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31121/how-can-i-automatically-upload-images-on-file-selection-rather-than-pressing-the/31453#31453)

Comment: I have search into file.js file in core modules but what happens if i add any confirmation alert on it, ajax is response  first than javascript calls. I do not underspend how to start..

Comment: can I use Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSubmit  function for manage_file form element events??? means can we use ajax.beforeSubmit for remove button events as i have search alot and do not get any solution.. please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I have hide remove button access. and then put my own remove button, and open dialog box in form to display popup box.

[image]

please see code.

`drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.dialog');

drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#clicky").live("click", function(){

        jQuery("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true ,height: 250,width: 350,
 buttons: [

            {

            text: "Cancel",

            click: function() {

                jQuery(this).dialog("close");

            }},

            {

                text: "Submit",

                click: function() {  

                     jQuery("#dialog-form").submit();

            }}

        ]});});});', 'inline');`