# instant upload after select file in a file or image field (quit upload button)

Tags: 7, files, media

In the normal fashion you have to select the file you want to upload in a file field or image field and then click "upload" button.

this is not very "user friendly"

How to upload the image or file just after the user selects it in the window without the necessity of click "upload" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [Drag & Drop Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload)

Here you just browse the file.

select the file and it will be automatically upload.

Comment: @SsouLlesS welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Autoupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoupload) module

> AutoUpload is a user interface (UI) enhancement that initiates
>   automatic upload of files minimizing the number of clicks required by
>   a user.
>
> Currently, users must select files, then press the "Upload" button. We
>   found users often don't realize a button press is necessary and
>   mistakenly think their image is uploaded when it's not.
>
> This module removes the extra button press and hides the "Upload"
>   button via JavaScript for a quicker, automatic file upload. When
>   JavaScript is not enabled, it falls back to the "Upload" button.

or you can check [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31121/how-can-i-automatically-upload-images-on-file-selection-rather-than-pressing-the) post.

Comment: this module has problems with jquery 1.10 how I use Zurb fundation that jquery version is required....